# data.table: Select n specific rows before & after other rows meeting a condition

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following example data table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("grp y exclude
a 1 0
a 2 0
a 3 0
a 4 1
a 5 0
a 7 1
a 8 0
a 9 0
a 10 0
b 1 0
b 2 0
b 3 0
b 4 1
b 5 0
b 6 1
b 7 1
b 8 0
b 9 0
b 10 0
c 5 1
d 1 0")
```

I want to select

1. by group `grp`
2. all rows that have `y==5`
3. and up to two rows before and after each row from 2 within the grouping.
4. but 3. only those rows that have `exclude==0`.

Assuming each group has max one row with `y==5`, this would yield the desired result for 1.-3.:

```
idx <- -2:2 # 2 rows before match, the matching row itself, and two rows after match
(row_numbers <- DT[,.I[{
                         x <- rep(which(y==5),each=length(idx))+idx 
                         x[x>0 & x<=.N]
                       }], by=grp]$V1)
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7 12 13 14 15 16 20
DT[row_numbers]
#     grp y exclude
#  1:   a 3       0
#  2:   a 4       1
#  3:   a 5       0 # y==5 + two rows before and two rows after
#  4:   a 7       1
#  5:   a 8       0
#  6:   b 3       0
#  7:   b 4       1
#  8:   b 5       0 # y==5 + two rows before and two rows after
#  9:   b 6       1
# 10:   b 7       1
# 11:   c 5       1 # y==5 + nothing, because the group has only 1 element
```

However, how do I incorporate 4. so that I get

```
#     grp  y exclude
#  1:   a  2       0
#  2:   a  3       0
#  3:   a  5       0
#  4:   a  8       0
#  5:   a  9       0
#  6:   b  2       0
#  7:   b  3       0
#  8:   b  5       0
#  9:   b  8       0
# 10:   b  9       0
# 11:   c  5       1
```

? Feels like I'm close, but I guess I looked too long at `head`s and `which`es, now, so I'd be thankful for some fresh ideas.

Comment: Is `y` always in a sequence like that?

Comment: Final output looks wrong. You've kept `(a,2)` even though this is more than two away from the `(a,5)` row...

Comment: @Frank - I think OP means the two rows nearest to y==5 for which exclude is false. I.e. these rows do not need to be adjacent to the y==5 row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close. This should do it:

```
row_numbers <- DT[exclude==0 | y==5, .I[{
    x <- rep(which(y==5), each=length(idx)) + idx 
    x[x>0 & x<=.N]
  }], by=grp]$V1
DT[row_numbers]
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I was so much focused on j in DT[..i,..j,..by] because of another problem that I totally overlooked this way of subsetting. :)

Answer (score 8):

A bit more simplified:

```
DT[DT[, rn := .I][exclude==0 | y==5][, rn[abs(.I - .I[y==5]) <= 2], by=grp]$V1]

 #   grp y exclude rn
 #1:   a 2       0  2
 #2:   a 3       0  3
 #3:   a 5       0  5
 #4:   a 8       0  7
 #5:   a 9       0  8
 #6:   b 2       0 11
 #7:   b 3       0 12
 #8:   b 5       0 14
 #9:   b 8       0 17
#10:   b 9       0 18
#11:   c 5       1 20
```

Comment: Great, the simplification brought me to a solution on another problem. Thx

Comment: For some reason this does not work if we change DT$y[2] <- 5. Then the index will point to a value lower than 1. Any suggestions on how to fix that?