# add column with data in rows before & after a condition

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

With inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821826/data-table-select-n-specific-rows-before-after-other-rows-meeting-a-condition), I came up with a solution to add a column with 1's 2 rows before and after y==5. Like this:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("grp y exclude
            a 1 0
            a 2 0
            a 3 0
            a 4 1
            a 5 0
            a 7 1
            a 8 0
            a 9 0
            a 10 0
            b 1 0
            b 2 0
            b 3 0
            b 4 1
            b 5 0
            b 6 1
            b 7 1
            b 8 0
            b 9 0
            b 10 0
            c 5 1
            d 1 0")

DT[DT[, rn := .I][, rn[abs(.I - .I[y==5]) <= 2], by=grp]$V1, xx:=1]
```

My problem is that if the condition is met too close to the top, it will throw a warning and not work properly:

```
DT$y[2] <- 5

DT[DT[, rn := .I][, rn[abs(.I - .I[y==5]) <= 2], by=grp]$V1, xx:=1]
Warning message:
In .I - .I[y == 5] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I suspect that the index will give numbers less than 1, but cant figure it out. Any suggestion to alter the code, so that it works under all conditions?

Wanted output:

```
    grp  y exclude xx
 1:   a  1       0  1
 2:   a  5       0  1
 3:   a  3       0  1
 4:   a  4       1  1
 5:   a  5       0  1
 6:   a  7       1  1
 7:   a  8       0  1
 8:   a  9       0  0
 9:   a 10       0  0
10:   b  1       0  0
11:   b  2       0  0
12:   b  3       0  1
13:   b  4       1  1
14:   b  5       0  1
15:   b  6       1  1
16:   b  7       1  1
17:   b  8       0  0
18:   b  9       0  0
19:   b 10       0  0
20:   c  5       1  1
21:   d  1       0  0
```

Comment: You say *add a column with 1's 2 rows before and after y==1.*...did you mean when *exclude == 1*?

Comment: Oh, so you mean when `y == 5`...? Please clarify

Comment: Can't you use (relevant parts of) [the answer by @dww](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822336/1851712) where the indices seem to be truncated to the relevant range of rows here: (`x[x>0 & x<=.N]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another alternative using `shift`

```
val <- 5L
DT[, xx := as.integer(
        Reduce(`|`, c(shift(y==val, 0L:2L, fill=FALSE), shift(y==val, 1L:2L, FALSE, "lead")))
    ),
    by=.(grp)]
DT
```

Incorporating Jaap's comment, using data.table version >= 1.12.0, code is shortened to

```
DT[, xx := +(Reduce(`|`, shift(y==v, -2L:2L, FALSE))), by=grp]
```

output:

```
    grp  y exclude xx
 1:   a  1       0  1
 2:   a  5       0  1
 3:   a  3       0  1
 4:   a  4       1  1
 5:   a  5       0  1
 6:   a  7       1  1
 7:   a  8       0  1
 8:   a  9       0  0
 9:   a 10       0  0
10:   b  1       0  0
11:   b  2       0  0
12:   b  3       0  1
13:   b  4       1  1
14:   b  5       0  1
15:   b  6       1  1
16:   b  7       1  1
17:   b  8       0  0
18:   b  9       0  0
19:   b 10       0  0
20:   c  5       1  1
21:   d  1       0  0
    grp  y exclude xx
```

Comment: with the latest version of [tag:data.table], you can simplify this to: ```DT[, xx := +(Reduce(`|`, shift(y == v, n = -2:2, fill = FALSE))), by = grp][]```

Comment: @Jaap - That looks nice, but I get the error: Error in +(Reduce(`|`, shift(y == v, n = -2:2, fill = FALSE))) : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: @JeppeOlsen did you define `v` with `v <- 5`?

Comment: @Jaap Yes and no. After setting v to 5 I get the Error in shift(y == v, n = -2:2, fill = FALSE) : 
  n must be non-negative integer values (>= 0) And setting n to some integer value gets me same error

Comment: as Jaap mentioned, you need the latest version of data.table (i.e. 1.12.0). see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3166 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3223

Comment: I needed to restart to get the update, but it works now. Thanks.

Comment: in addition to @chinsoon12's comment: data.table 1.12.0 is on CRAN [since 3 days ago](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)